# Wanted: metric in which the volume of euclidean space is finite

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

With the motivation to give a small mini-course with rudiments of Riemannian geometry to students of the end of the graduation in mathematics.
 I aspire to show how much the environment changes according to the way I choose to measure distances.
 For example, let $\mathbb{R}^ 2$ be the canonical metric.  Using the definition of volume, it follows that vol of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ "is" infinite.
 Now let $g = (dx^ {2} + dy ^ {2}).y ^ {- 2} $(metric of Lobachveski), again using the volume definition, I have gained $vol (\mathbb{R }^ {2}) = \infty$. 
which does not give finite volume.  how could I find a metric for $\mathbb{R} ^ 2$ whose volume of this manifold was finite?

Comment: Maybe this works: compose the [gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) with the inverse of the [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) to get a map from the plane to the disc, then pull back the metric on the disc to the plane calculate the volume.

Comment: Is it important that the new metric be related to the Eulicidean metric by a conformal factor, as the Lobachevskian metric is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we express our metric in polar coordinates, it becomes a bit easier to see what to do.  Let's suppose that our desired metric is related to the Euclidean metric by a conformal transformation of the form:
$$
ds^2 = \Omega^2(r) (dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2).
$$
Then the volume spanned by the coordinate range $r = [0,\infty)$ and $\theta = [0, 2 \pi]$ is
$$
V = \iint \sqrt{g} \, d^2x = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\infty \Omega^2(r) r \, dr \, d \theta = 2 \pi \int_0^\infty \Omega^2(r) r \, dr.
$$
So for any function $\Omega(r)$ for which this integral converges, the volume of the above coordinate range will be finite.

In particular, $\Omega(r)$ must fall off faster than $1/r$ as $r \to \infty$ for this integrand to be finite, so let's try
$$
\Omega(r) = \frac{1}{1+r^2},
$$
which corresponds in the coordinates $x$ and $y$ to
$$
ds^2 = \frac{1}{(1 + x^2 + y^2)^2}(dx^2 + dy^2).
$$
Then we have
$$
V = 2 \pi \int_0^\infty \frac{r dr}{(1+r^2)^2} = \pi.
$$

Comment: This is nicely motivated and explained. I was thinking of a different approach -- to find an embedding of $\mathbb R^2$ into a compact Riemannian manifold, and use that to pull back the metric to $\mathbb R^2$. I was going to suggest using the inverse of [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection), which embeds $\mathbb R^2$ into $S^2$ and misses only one point. When you pull back the round metric from the sphere, you get this same metric, up to a constant multiple!